# Closing the ends of double line in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to close the ends of a double line. Tikz does not provide a built-in option for this as far as I understood. What is the best way to achieve this, including forked double lines? (perhaps use bar type arrow?)

A sample code is given below. I closed the ends manually in the second line.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

%A double line with ends are not closed
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width = 2mm, double distance = 4mm] (0,0) -- (10cm,10cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

%A double line with ends are closed - manually created
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width = 8mm] (0,0) -- (10cm, 10);
\draw [line width = 4mm, white] (1.41mm,1.41mm) -- (10cm-1.41mm, 10cm-1.41mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Double Lines - Tikz]

**Update:** Based on the answer provided, I would like to reinforce my question as follows: How about the forked (crossed, intersections) double lines? I have provided a simple but not effective solution. Is there a more robust solution?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

%Double lines with ends are closed with "line cap=rect"
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width = 2mm, double distance = 4mm, line cap=rect] (0,0) -- (10cm,0cm);
\draw[line width = 2mm, double distance = 4mm, line cap=rect] (5cm,0cm) -- (7cm,5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

%Forked (Crossed) double lines
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width = 2mm, double distance = 4mm, line cap=rect] (5cm,0cm) -- (7cm,5cm);
\draw[line width = 2mm, double distance = 4mm, line cap=rect] (0,0) -- (10cm,0cm);
\draw[line width = 4mm, white] (5cm,0cm) -- (7cm,5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are `line cap=round` and `line cap=rect`. The default is `line cap=butt`. These are all possibilities --- in the manner that PDF standard provides only these three. (See **8.4.3.3 Line Cap Style**)

Ti*k*Z does provides the possibilities to generate different `line cap`. For instance, all arrow tips could be classified as `line cap`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}

\begin{document}

%A double line with ends are not closed
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width = 2mm, double distance = 4mm] (0,0) -- (10cm,10cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

%A double line with ends are closed - manually created
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width = 2mm, double distance = 4mm,line cap=round] (0,0) -- (10cm,10cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width = 2mm, double distance = 4mm,line cap=rect] (0,0) -- (10cm,10cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## In respond to new question

The solution is simpler than you thought.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width = 2mm, double distance = 4mm,line cap=rect](0,0)--(10,0)(5,0)--(7,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

OK... I know someone would say it is ugly. So let me repeat one point.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width = 2mm, double distance = 4mm,line cap=rect](0,0)--(10,0)(7,5)--(5,0)--(7,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

## Caution! do this at your own risk

Currently `line cap` is defined as follows (`tikz.code.tex` line 105)

> ```
> \tikzoption{line cap}{\tikz@addoption{\csname pgfset#1cap\endcsname}}
> ```

One can override it by `/.is choice`. Ti*k*Z manual actually mentioned this. (It has never ceased to surprise me.)

[image]
[image]

The interesting part is, the author exchanged the meaning of `butt` and `round`. Guess if he did this intentionally.

## Just one more thing

Arrow tips are, currently, put on the two ends of the last subpath. On the other hands `line cap`s are, as shown above, put at every ends of subpaths. Probably one can manage to configure the behavior of arrow tips. But then one need to write a parser for `\draw[arrows={<-> <->}]...`.

Comment: What is the risk here?

Comment: @percusse your computer will crash... just kidding. What I want to say is that `line cap` (as well as `line join`) is pretty low-level --- as low as the PDF standard. So in the first place it is hard to build more choices, no matter on lower layer or on higher layer. Even if we can, one may lose some efficiency. And after all: one need not to reinvent arrow tips.

Comment: Ah OK, I misread *do this at your own risk* then. These are PostScript graphical path properties by the way.